# Webpack how to negative match resource query

Tags: javascript, webpack

How can I add a resource query to my Webpack configuration so that if a require statement contains a query string, Webpack skips the loader I've specified in the configuration file. Consider the following configuration:

```
test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif|ico|webp)$/,
resourceQuery: /(?!ni-ignore)/i,
use: [
  {
    loader: "url-loader",
    options: {
      limit: 8192,
      fallback: "file-loader",
      publicPath: `/static/images/`,
      outputPath: `/static/images/`,
      name: "[name]-[hash].[ext]"
    }
  }
]
```

I want Webpack to skip the rule if a require statement contains `ni-ignore` query.

```
// should skip the rule
const image = require("./image.jpg?ni-ignore");

// should follow the rule
const image = require("./image.jpg");
```

Is there any way to add a negative resource query matcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
`resourceQuery: /^((?!ni-ignore).)*$/i`

It seems that a part was missing in regex.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: It works, but when there is no query param at all, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but in case someone still needs this, **resourceQuery** now **accepts negative rules** in the form of:

```
resourceQuery: { not: [/raw/] },
```

See https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#replacing-inline-loader-syntax for more details.